# Spinning disc stress distribution

Tags: materials, stresses, acceleration

For a thin spinning disc, is the boundary condition on the outer surface that the radial stress is zero? If so, how is this consistent with the fact that the outer surface of the disc has a centripetal acceleration inwards (I think I've misunderstood the application of D'Alembert's principle).

Edit:

In Strength of Materials Part II by Timeshenko (Page 214), the example is given of a circular disc rotating about the axis of symmetry which is perpendicular to the disc. The equilibrium equation, including the inertia force acting on the element is stated:

$$
\sigma_t -\sigma_r -r\frac{d\sigma_r}{dr} - \rho\omega^2r^2=0
$$

In which $\sigma_{t,r}$ are the tangential and radial stresses respectively, $r$ is the radius (variable). $\rho$ is the density and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

The text goes on to state that a boundary condition for the radial stress is that

$$
\sigma_r(r_{outer}) = 0
$$

I am not sure how this is consistent with an element on the outside of the disc having an acceleration towards the centre of the disc on account of its rotation? (Clearly the book is right, as I have seen this in several other places!)

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you please provide sources (with links) for the statements you are asking about?  That will make it more likely that folks can provide you with a useful answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you.

The example source I have is quite old (a 3rd edition of Strength of Materials Part II by Timoshenko). I will update the question accordingly

Comment: OK, then I'm guessing that the radial stress  at radius $R_n$ is caused by material in the disk at radius  $r > R_n$  . Since there is no material outside the rim, you get that boundary condition.

Comment: Thank you - that does make sense!